# Session is lost and User logs out when JSON format error occurs in UI

Tags: jquery, session, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, cluster-computing

We have a web-application deployed on Cluster environment (Weblogic 10.3.6 server) and we are replicating the session on all the nodes.

We have a search Textbox where we could search for items. Sometimes I get a JSON format Error dialog on UI with this message (5 out of 10 times I see this error):
    *DataTables Warning: JSON Data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error*

I get logged out of my application when I get the above error, I don't see any exceptions logged in the log files, I have checked both the Application specific log and Server logs.

This happens only in clustered environment and I get the above JSON error only in clustered environment but not on single server.
**We Use JQuery, Spring MVC in the Presentation-tier, Should the FORM Beans used implement Serializable(java.io.Serializable)**

It would be great if some can guide me in the right direction

Comment: Have you tried looking at the response that's coming back by using a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or even the network tab in your browser's debug tools? Then you can see if you're actually getting invalid JSON back or maybe the parse error is because you're actually getting redirected to the login page because of a session replication issue or something.

Comment: I looked at the debug console in Chrome but I didn't see any JSON errors but they were some calls to the Methods which were not there are not allowed when the list got loaded but even this errors occur in the SINGLE node environment and the session would not be lost its only in the Clustered environment its getting lost. I will check with FIDDLER. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Its the session replication issue: After Logging IN and searching for a item in the application, the JSessionId changed and it was re-directed to Login page.

Comment: The Funny thing is: If I don't click any button in the application, I get the same JSessionID back but it gets chenaged after couple of operations.

Comment: This is the Weblogic Configuration I am using for specifying to replicate if clustered in weblogic-application.xml of EAR:     <wls:session-descriptor>
        <wls:persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</wls:persistent-store-type>
        <wls:sharing-enabled>true</wls:sharing-enabled>
    </wls:session-descriptor>

Comment: Have you verified that the session cookie is being sent with the ajax request? It sounds like either the cookie isn't being sent or else the server you're hitting doesn't have a copy of the session.